# android layout of relativelayout in a dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

It may seem a little stupid but I just cannot figure out why.

The view I expect is as below. I want TextView A to be center horizontal while TextView B alignLeft of A and above A.

[image]

when i try declare B after A (using layout_alignleft and layout_above in B)in the layout xml then TextView B cannot show and findviewId method becomes chaos.
if i try declare B before A (using layout_alignleft in B,using layout_below in A  ), then as u can guess TextView B just aligns to the left of the whole view rather than TextView A.

This happens in a DIALOG view.Of course I know how to display it in a activity...When it comes to dialog view just seems absurd

So here comes the question,am i stupid?

Comment: No you aren't stupid. You just haven't tried much. I would suggest use Linear layout instead of Relativelayout

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir but how can i get the effect of  "one align left of another"? too confused...

Comment: Don't put questions just like that..atleast put few efforts before you post a question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, this works for me:

Do this while showing dialog,

```
Dialog dlg = new Dialog(this);
dlg.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
dlg.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

or, you can fix dialog height like:

```
dlg.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 450);
```

or   `android:layout_height="300dp"`

check sample code [here](http://hastebin.com/edijozavaj.xml).

Comment: It do work like a charm.BTW,do u know why "setlayout" works and why normal trick fails?really want a explanation lol

Comment: Do u find that one of the two parameters of setLayout method must be MATCH_PARENT so that alignleft works. But the dialog will other two wide or high,anyway to wrap content?

Comment: I posted one more answer, try by change your dialog layout like that. now no need to use 'setLayout' method in your activity.

Comment: already replied urs,ur new trick must rely on the center TextView is longer than the alignLeft one.Lol. Whatever ,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use toLeftOf property to declare TextView B.

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtA"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly like the picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView B align left of A"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="TextView A"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: u can try to apply this to a dialog then sth interesting u'll find. That is exactly what confuess me

Answer (score 0):

check the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EEEEEE">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="HAI"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="HELLO"
    android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textView1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your dialog layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView B align left of A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView A" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In this case the length of this two TextView will make it into two kinds. LOL

Comment: As per my knoledge, in this case, either you should make that height 'match_parent' or fix dialog height.

Comment: If you keep wrap_content, main layout will rendering first then, textview in center, so even you give other dependents on that textview, those are not able to view in case of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that alignLeft or alignStart doesn't work in a dialog